# Numerate and echo array keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, echo, enumerate

In my php code, i'm collecting all validation error messages into one array called `$errors`. Is it possible to echo all array elements like that: "1) Error 1 2) Error 2 ... " and so on?

Comment: Not really clear … You want to loop an array? Sure, PHP can do that …

Comment: What i wanna do is, to create new var $message and assign "1) Error 1 2) Error 2 ... " style message into it. Error messages will taken from $errors array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really unclear. Anyway if I understand your problem, this should work:

If you need all the messages in a **single string** use this:

```
$i = 1;
$message = '';
foreach($errors as $value)
{
   $message .= "$i) Error $value\n";
   $i++;
}
```

If you need to have them in a **array**, use this one instead:

```
$i = 1;
$message = array();
foreach($errors as $value)
{
   $message[] = "$i) Error $value";
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: What i wanna do is, to create new var `$message` and assign "1) Error 1 2) Error 2 ... " style message into it. Error messages will taken from $errors array

Answer (score 1):

The [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) construct is suited well for this:

```
foreach($errors as $key => $value) {
  printf('%s) %s', htmlspecialchars($key), htmlspecialchars($value));
}
```

I hope I understood your question, it's not really clear what you want to do

Comment: What i wanna do is, to create new var $message and assign "1) Error 1 2) Error 2 ... " style message into it. Error messages will taken from $errors array

Answer (score 0):

The good ol' c style is totally valid php:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($error); $i++)
{
    echo "" . ($i+1) . ") " . $error[$i];
}
```

Comment: This will not work if the key are not numerical or numerical and not sequential.

Comment: What i wanna do is, to create new var and assign "1) Error 1 2) Error 2 ... " style message into it. what if i declare '$message=array();' before for loop then place `message[]=` instead of `echo`.?

Comment: so then, create a var `$message = "";` and instead of the echo line above, do the following: `$message .= ($i+1) . ") " . $error[$i] . "\n";` (assuming of course, that the keys in the array are numbers, as Aurelio De Rosa pointed out :)). This concatenates the current expression to what message already has in it.